# Textarea returns empty value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a form which takes three values Roomname, Experience and Rating. This data is then submitted to a database. The issue I'm facing is through my Roomname and Rating is getting submitted perfectly, the data I enter in textarea is giving me empty result in database. I have tried every way but I'm not able to solve this issue. Only this is the issue, other code is working fine.

Please help!!!

Here is the code:

```html
<?php
include 'db.php';
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--User's CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/feedback.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    <!--Fonts-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Font Awesome JS-->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1033686ccb.js"></script>
    <!--JQuery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <?php include 'inner-navbar.php'; 
            error_reporting(0);
        ?>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="feedback">
            <h3 class="mb-5">Your Feedback</h3>
                <form method="post" id="feedback-form">
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Room Name: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select name="selectedRoomName" id="selectedRoomName" class="form-control">
                            <?php
                            $selectQuery="SELECT*FROM bookings where firstname='".$_SESSION['firstname']."';";
                            $selectQueryResult=mysqli_query($conn,$selectQuery);
                            if($selectQueryResult){
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectQueryResult)){
                                    echo '<option value="'.$row["roomName"].'">'.$row["roomName"].'</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-4">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Your Experience: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Experience" name="experience" id="experience"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-5">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Your Rating: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-index="0"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-index="1"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-index="2"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-index="3"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-index="4"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit Feedback</button>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['rating'])){
                            $roomName=$_POST['selectedRoomName'];
                            $experience=$_POST['experience'];
                            $rating=$_POST['rating'];
                            $submitQuery="INSERT INTO feedback(roomName,experience,rating) VALUES('$roomName','$experience','$rating');";
                            $submitQueryRes=mysqli_query($conn,$submitQuery);
                            if($submitQueryRes){
                                echo '<script>alert("Your Feedback has been Successfully Submitted!");</script>';
                            }else{
                                echo '<script>alert("Error: '.$rating.'");</script>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedRoomName=$("#selectedRoomName").val();
    var experience=$("#experience").val();
    var rating=-1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.fa-star').click(function(){
            rating=parseInt($(this).data('index'));
        });

        $('.fa-star').mouseover(function(){
            resetStarColors();
            var value=parseInt($(this).data('index'));

            for(var i=0;i<=value;i++){
                $('.fa-star:eq('+i+')').css('color','#eb9e34');
            }
        });
        $('.fa-star').mouseleave(function(){
            resetStarColors();
            if(rating!=-1){
                for(var i=0;i<=rating;i++){
                $('.fa-star:eq('+i+')').css('color','#eb9e34');
            }
            }
            
        });
        function resetStarColors(){
            $('.fa-star').css('color','black');
        }
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'feedback.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                    selectedRoomName: selectedRoomName,
                    experience: experience,
                    rating: rating
                    
                },
                success: function(){
                    alert(experience);
                }
            });
            
        });
    }); 
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `error_reporting(0);` from your code

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
var selectedRoomName=$("#selectedRoomName").val();
var experience=$("#experience").val();
```

inside your .click() method.

Comment: Oh thanks so much solved the issue! Really grateful. Why was it happening? var was globally declared right?

Comment: No, you were not assigning the var when the submit event is fired, it was assigned during the initialisation of the script, at which point the value will be empty. Then, when the user fills in the textarea and submits, it was picking up the earlier empty values.